# How to get Azure Cosmos DB database/container size?

Tags: .net, azure, rest, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

Currently, I am trying to get Azure Cosmos DB SQL API account data volume. I fount solution using PowerShell Get-AzMetric command. Does anybody know how it can be solved using .NET SDK or REST API?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anybody know how it can be solved using .NET SDK or REST API?

Azure PowerShell is simply a wrapper over REST API. If you run your PowerShell Cmdlet with `-Debug` parameter, you should see the REST API call being made by the Cmdlet to fetch the data.

For example, if I trace the request/response through Azure Portal for checking the storage size of my database, I noticed the following request is being sent:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<my-subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<my-resource-group>/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts/<my-cosmosdb-account-name>/databases/<my database rid e.g 2942BA==>/metrics?
api-version=2014-04-01&
$filter=(name.value eq 'Available Storage' or name.value eq 'Data Size' or name.value eq 'Index Size') 
and endTime eq 2020-04-10T09%3A10%3A00.000Z 
and startTime eq 2020-04-10T08%3A10%3A00.000Z and timeGrain eq duration'PT5M'
```

You could do the same and find out the exact REST API call being made.

Answer (score 1):

The rest api is provided by Gaurav and you can retrieve Monitor metrics and metric definitions using the Azure .NET SDK releases `0.16.0-preview` and `0.16.1-preview`.

The following code is get Azure Cosmos DB database size. Fore more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/monitor-dotnet-metrics-api/monitor-dotnet-metrics-api/).

```
var tenantId = "xxxxxxxx";
var clientSecret = "xxxxxxxx";
var clientId = "xxxxxxxx";
var subscriptionId = "xxxxxxxx";
var serviceCreds = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
var monitorClient = new MonitorClient(serviceCreds);
monitorClient.SubscriptionId = subscriptionId;
var resourceUrl = $"subscriptions/xxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/xxxxxxxx/databases/xxxxxx/metrics";
var metricNames = "name.value eq 'Data Size'"; 
string timeGrain = " and timeGrain eq duration'PT5M'";
string startDate = string.Format(" and startTime eq {0}", DateTime.Now.AddHours(-3).ToString("o"));
string endDate = string.Format(" and endTime eq {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("o"));
var odataFilterMetrics = new ODataQuery<Metric>(
    string.Format(
      "{0}{1}{2}{3}",
      metricNames,
      timeGrain,
      startDate,
      endDate));
var metrics = monitorClient.Metrics.ListAsync(resourceUrl, odataFilterMetrics).Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be achieved by using the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/common-cosmosdb-rest-response-headers) of cosmos db, when you make request, **`x-ms-resource-usage`** header in the response object has this data

```
x-ms-resource-usage :
  - documentSize=5577
  - documentsSize=4422147
  - documentsCount=4889177
  - collectionSize=5711285
```